# paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions is not called while restoreCompletedTransactions

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

Hi I need to implement the restore functionality in Inapp-Purchase, for this made a button "Restore" which is calling  method

```
-(void)restorePurchasedProductsWithProductId:(NSString*)prodID
{
    _productIdsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    productID = [prodID retain];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

It gives me a popup to enter the password of apple id.And after doing that nothing happens.

I read somewhere that it calls

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

So i did like this

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"paymentQueue");
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"restored");
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is the above method is not calling neither this

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

nor

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
```

I have  also included the required protocols,

Can some body help me why these delegate methods are not calling for restore process.
I am trying it with test account.

Answer (score 12):

You need to make sure the class that implements `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` and `paymentQueue: restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` is registered as an observer for your payment queue.

If you've written this code in a `UIViewController`, try adding this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

and in `viewDidDisappear`:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

I also am facing a problem like one;

After research & modification, I realized that:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]
```

method is not implemented immediately.

Normally, i check transaction.transactionReceipt and send it to my server and after all that I send a callback to finish Transaction. Finally, i understood the problem not calling finish transaction immediately. When i change my code, my app works.

Interesting part was, when i test in sandbox environment, everything works fine. However, in AppStore app did not work well. When i made this modification, my problem was solved.